# Mongodb- Add unique index on an existing collection

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to learn indexing in Mongodb. I created a database and a collection as follows:

```
use mydb
db.createCollection("myFirstCollection")
one={name:"Helios"}
two={name:"Kepler"}
db.myFirstCollection.insert(one)
db.myFirstCollection.insert(two)
```

I was able to list out my results as follows:

```
db.myFirstCollection.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53cde256f8807057b6bd827b"), "name" : "Helios" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53cde25bf8807057b6bd827c"), "name" : "kepler" }
```

I want to add unique index on the field `name`. But when I tried, got the following error

```
db.myFirstCollection.ensureIndex({name:1},{unique:true})

{
        "createdCollectionAutomatically" : false,
        "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.myFirstCollection.$name_1  dup key: { : null }",
        "code" : 11000
}
```

I am unable to figure out the mistake what I am making. Please help.

Comment: What's the db.myFirstCollectio.getIndexes() shows?

Comment: It works fine when I try your code in the shell.  That error message implies there are other docs in `myFirstCollection` that don't have a `name` field.

Comment: Try specifying `sparse` as `true` so that if documents don't have the field, they will not be included in the index. ie: `db.myFirstCollection.ensureIndex({name:1},{unique:true, sparse: true})`

Comment: Yes I verified the collection. It was having a another document without name field { "_id" : ObjectId("53cd53382e18fe3c3df582c9"), "i" : 0 }. Got the mistake. It works fine after I remove this :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having issues, also take note that field names are case sensitive.

So creating an index on `{field1 : 1}` is not the same as `{Field1 : 1}`

Answer (score 0):

Please see missing field section here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/

You can only have a single document that does not contain the unique index existing in the collection.