# MeanJS MongoDb insert issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm creating an application using MEANJS. I've a mongoose schema defined like this:

```
 var UserdetailSchema = new Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    userName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
        },
    mobile: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    suburb: {
        type: String
        },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    }
    });

mongoose.model('Userdetail', UserdetailSchema);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is after login user is redirected to edit view to update rest of the info like "mobile, suburb, address" etc which is in userdetails schema.

This is my controller. I've changed default create() method to the following: I'm redirecting to the edit it as soon as the first step of inserting is complete.

```
// Create new Userdetail for current user
    function create(FullName,UserName) {
        // Create new Userdetail object
        var userdetail = new Userdetails ({
            fullName: FullName,
            userName: UserName
        });

        // Redirect after save
        userdetail.$save(function(response) {
            $location.path('userdetails/' + response._id+'/edit');
            console.log(response._id);
            // Clear form fields
            //$scope.name = '';
        }, function(errorResponse) {
            console.log(errorResponse.data.message);
            $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
        });
    };
```

To create a user details I'm only inserting fullName, and userName as a first step and updating it later.

issue is, it is only allowing me 1 userdetails to insert and if I try to insert another userdetails of another user. it gives an error "Name already exists", though there is no name in the schema.

Server side code to create userdetails

```
/**
 * Create a Userdetail
 */
    exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var userdetail = new Userdetail(req.body);
    userdetail.user = req.user;

    userdetail.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(userdetail);
        }
    });
};
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the error you are going and show the code where you are doing the insert. Just seeing your schema doesn't help identify the problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply "ThrowsException" I've included my updated create() method. I hope it helps now.

Comment: What about your server side code. your client isn't what is trying to write to the database.

Comment: I've not made any changes to server side.  I've included my serverside create method code.

Comment: I got it working after droping my collection "userdetails" from shell and trying inserting again.   I followed this link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878847/mongodb-add-unique-index-on-an-existing-collection . It was more of MongoDB issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after droping my collection "userdetails" from shell and trying inserting again.   I followed this link   [Mongodb- Add unique index on an existing collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878847/mongodb-add-unique-index-on-an-existing-collection) . It was more of MongoDB issue.